# PHP While loop in Table in Form

Tags: php, forms, while-loop

I'm trying to create a Table where you can 'Sign Off' items populating it. Currently the table looks to be populated fine, however when you go to 'Sign Off' an item - it will only act on the latest mysql row ['directory'] as well as the latest text field accompanying it.

When I say 'Sign Off' I mean to insert someone's initials into the mysql table row associated with that item. I first of course need to get the POST submission handled correctly.

That probably wasn't articulated perfectly, so please take a look at my current code;

```
echo "<form action='signoff.php' method='post' id='signoffform' style='display:inline;'>";
echo "<p3><table id='myTable3' class='tablesorter'> 
<thead> 
<tr>
    <th>To Delete</th>
    <th>Directory</th> 
    <th>Space Used</th>
</tr> 
</thead>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='signoff' id='signoff' form='signoffform' /><button>Sign Off</button> Signed Off By:" . $row['signoff'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='dir' id='dir' form='signoffform' value='" . $row['directory'] . "' readonly /></td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['used'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table></p3>";
echo "</form>";
```

signoff.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST["signoff"];
echo "<br />";
echo $_POST["dir"];
?>
```

Please feel free to request more info

Comment: If your code is working, you should post this in Code Review site.

Comment: It isn't working properly. Please take a look at my blurb again, Thanks!

Comment: oh ok, sorry, I didn't catch what your question was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... when you go to 'Sign Off' an item - it will only act on the latest mysql row ['directory'] as well as the latest text field accompanying it.

The problem is because of your `name` attributes, `name='signoff'` and `name=dir`. When you loop through the result set, the `name` attribute value gets overwritten in each iteration. Hence whatever button you click, you'll always get the last row values.

So **the solution** would be like this:

Change your `while` loop in the following way,

```
// your code

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='signoff[".$row['directory']."]' id='signoff' form='signoffform' /><button>Sign Off</button> Signed Off By:" . $row['signoff'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='dir[".$row['directory']."]' id='dir' form='signoffform' value='" . $row['directory'] . "' readonly /></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['used'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

// your code
```

And on *signoff.php* page, process your form in the following way,

```
foreach($_POST['dir'] as $dir){
    if(!empty($_POST['signoff'][$dir])){
        $signoff = $_POST['signoff'][$dir];

        // That how you can get $dir and the corresponing $signoff value

    }
}
```

---

**Sidenote:** If you want to see the entire `$_POST` array structure, do `var_dump($_POST);` on *signoff.php* page.